# How to load kernel module while system is booting up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I cannot load kernel module when the system boots up. I found one article that suggests me to try the following steps:

**(a) Create directory for `kmodule`(the module I created):**
`# mkdir -p /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/mymodule`

**(b) Copy `kmodule` to that directory:**
`# cp kmodule.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/mymodule/`

**(c) Edit `/etc/modules file` and add a line to it that consist your module name. In my case, it's `kmodule` as per the following:**
`# vi /etc/modules`

```
1 # /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
2 #
3 # This file contains the names of kernel modules that should beloaded
4 # at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
5 kmodule
```

**(d) Reboot the system to see changes. Use `lsmod` command to check if the module is loaded or not.**
`# lsmod | grep kmodule`

My Problem: it's not loaded when I reboot the system and when I debug using  cmd `$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep kmodule`.

I found this:

```
May 20 15:40:14 SARATHI kernel: [17499.486762] kmodule: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
May 20 15:40:14 SARATHI kernel: [17499.486800] kmodule: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
May 20 19:31:46 SARATHI systemd-modules-load[243]: Failed to find module 'kmodule'
```

What does that mean? How to resolve it?

*NOTE: I'm new to kernel module and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Also, note that when I loaded manually using insmod cmd, it's successfully loaded.*

Comment: I have been using `/etc/module` for loading modules at boot time for a while now. Can you please write the exact command for `insmod`. Are you giving the full path of `.ko` or `.o` file?

Comment: also how about `modprobe kmodule` ?

Comment: Actually, I'm saying that when I do manual loading using cmd `$insmod kmodule.ko`(in working directory) it's working fine.but I want to load it automatically and my  problem is as mentioned in above log file and thanks for reply and all.

Comment: `depmod -a` hopefully fixes this.